netdelay on Android emulator is being ignored
I have an app that I am running on Android emulator. It is communicating via a WebSocket with a web app running on the same local machine.
I have configured the emulator to have

network speed of  1000 bits/s
network delay of 10,000ms


While I can see that the network speed is being applied to the comms, I am not seeing any network latency either up or down. Ie Messages sent from the Android app arrive immediately at the server and those from the server arrive immediately at the Android app.
Why isn't the emulator network latency being applied?
